# Unable to delete Azure Recovery Service Vault

Tags: azure

I'm unable to delete Azure Recovery Serice Vault. No resources are attached to it but it's still throwing error 
**

> Vault cannot be deleted as there are existing resources within the
>   vault. Please ensure there are no backup items, protected servers or
>   backup management servers associated with this vault. Unregister the
>   following containers associated with this vault before proceeding for
>   deletion

**

I've checked all of these places and nothing is there. Also, I've removed all the resources. Is there any other way to delete it forcefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you error is not complete.  I have seen this error a few times and it should have provided you the container to Unregistered.

I see this normally when Azure SQL Database long term backup retention is enabled, if that's the case article below should help you out.

[Configure long-term backup retention - Azure SQL database - powershell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure#powershell)

Those backup go not show as backup or replicated item but you should see backup storage usage.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, eventually found out some Azure SQL backups were still in the vault via PowerShell. I had to remove each of them manually via PowerShell. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete any protected servers and their data from the vault before you are able to delete the vault its self.

You can do this in the portal by going to the vault, into the "Backup Items" tab, This will list what backups there are, click on virtual machines, then select each one and go to "Stop backup" and remove data. Once these are all deleted you should be able to delete the vault.

Comment: I had deleted the entire resource group but it failed to remove the Vault. I have verified all places and nothing is showing up.

Comment: Yes, the resource group will not delete as the vault cannot be deleted, as it sill has protected items in it. You need to go into the valut item and delete these. See my edit.

Comment: Yes as Sam Mentioned. You need to manually navigate to the vault and ensure it is completely empty. In addition, if you have VMs you are backing up you need to ensure to turn off the backups.

Comment: I manually navigated to each location and everything was removed as nothing was showing up on the list. But, eventually found out some Azure SQL backups were still in the vault via PowerShell. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this before when all VM level backups were removed however the vault would still fail when attempting to deleting it.

If the Azure Recovery Services agent was installed onto Windows Server for file level backup and the VM was deleted then there's possibility that the backups still exist inside the Azure Recovery Services vault.

To remove these backups, Backup Infrastructure (Manage) -> Protected Services -> Azure Backup Agent. Within there you'll be able to delete any file level backups on the vault. Combined with the removal of the VM level backups, this should allow you to successfully delete the vault.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly for me - specially since you clearly described how to remove these backups. I had gone through many online solutions but yours worked the best. Thank you for sharing it to help others.